# Access SQL - Table Join with IIF

Tags: sql, ms-access

### Table [One]

- id - number
- s - text
- i - text
- e - text
- d - number

### Table [Two]

- id - number
- s - text
- i - text
- e - text
- d - number

### Table [One] Data

1,a,b,b,7
2,a,b,b,7
3,a,b,c,11
4,b,a,a,21

### Table [Two] Data

1,a,b,b,3
2,a,b,c,12
3,b,a,a,4

Issue: Show result set displaying records if Table [Two] d < Table [One] d joining s,i,e .

Desired Result: Table [Two] s,i,e,d Table [One] d based on s

Any help would be great, I'm not familiar with Access Syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use Design View of the Access query designer to build the query. You can examine the syntax it produces by switching to SQL View.

If I understand the requirements correctly, this SQL may be what you want:

```sql
SELECT
    t2.s,
    t2.i,
    t2.e,
    t2.d AS t2_d,
    t1.d AS t1_d
FROM
    Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
    ON
            t1.s = t2.s
        AND t1.i = t2.i
        AND t1.e = t2.e
WHERE t2.d < t1.d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT two.*, one.d
FROM one INNER JOIN two on one.s = two.s AND one.i = two.i AND two one.e = two.e 
WHERE two.d < one.d
```